# Can't understand which one is unallocated space in ubuntu installation?

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, partitioning

This might seem a really stupid question. I have windows 8 in my laptop. I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside it. My hard drive is supposed to have 20gb unallocated space in it to install Ubuntu. Now I am in the installation phase. And I can't seem to find it. Now there is a window which says installation type. there are options like `dev/sda1`, `dev/sda2` `dev/sda3` etc. But I can't seem to understand which one to select. Please help me. And thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of [http://superuser.com/questions/627738/cant-understand-which-partition-is-unallocated-space-during-an-ubuntu-installat](http://superuser.com/questions/627738/cant-understand-which-partition-is-unallocated-space-during-an-ubuntu-installat) by eddard.stark.

Answer (score 0):

Partitions are numbered from 1; `sda1, sda2`, etc. `sda1` is probably your windows partition, and `sda` refers to the whole disk (physical).  So `sda` would be the first physical Disk, `sdb` the second, and so on.

`sda1` would be the first partition, the second partition would be `sda2`, and so on.

Since you set aside a 20GB partition, look for the `sadx` that has 20GB unallocated space.